How can i mint token again?
I made spl token on Solana
But i have some questions
How can i mint more tokens later ? Because it didn't gives me any private things except a wallet secret key
So how can i mint more coins in feature?! And how can i make sure some one else can't mint my token
I use this document and made my token
https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/how-to-create-a-token

If you followed that guide then at some point you'll have done spl-token mint <mint address> 100. Just do that again with any amount to mint more to yourself.
Every token has a mint authority, which is the only account that can mint tokens. This can also be revoked so that nobody can mint any more and the supply can never be increased. By default you'll be the mint authority though, and nobody else can mint your token.
You can check this by viewing your token on https://explorer.solana.com?cluster=devnet (you'll probably want the devnet cluster if you used that guide). If you search your mint address it'll show the mint authority.
For example here's the USDC mainnet mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v You can see the mint authority is 2wmVCSfPxGPjrnMMn7rchp4uaeoTqN39mXFC2zhPdri9. This is the only account that can mint USDC tokens.
And here's the Kin mainnet mint: https://explorer.solana.com/address/kinXdEcpDQeHPEuQnqmUgtYykqKGVFq6CeVX5iAHJq6 You can see there is no mint authority and the supply is fixed.
